# sleep/pause function in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I have a question about pine script. I need a sleep/pause function, I need this because I have a tradingbot that has a delay of 1 sec. As in when tradingview sends the webhook notification it takes the bot 1 sec to buy on my broker. Because of this the results tradingview gives me from the past year are not accurate, and I want more accurate results. You can ignore the strategy code, that's pure to make it more specific what I want.

```
//@version=4
strategy("xx")
emaLong = ema(close, 50)
emaShort = ema(close, 20)

longCondition = crossover()
shortCondition = crossover()

if longCondition
     sleep/pause of 1 sec <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< That's where I want a short pause.
     strategy.entry()

if shortCondition
     sleep/pause of 1 sec <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< That's where I want a short pause.
     strategy.entry()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done, because Pine processes bar per bar, and maximum execution time per bar is limited to 200ms (judging from a max loop time error I got).

The code below is an attempt at waiting 1 second, but can't get it working due to the mentioned 200ms error, but I'll leave it here for you to fiddle with it.

```
//@version=4
study("xx", overlay=true)

var int[] arr = array.new_int(na)
var int t = na

if barstate.islast and barstate.isconfirmed
    t := timenow
    array.push(arr, t)
    for i = 0 to 5000000
        if timenow - t >= 1000 // 1000ms = 1 second
            array.push(arr, t)
            break // get out of loop

    label.new(bar_index, high, "#elements=" + tostring(array.size(arr)))

plot(na)
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answering I appriciate it. I can't get this to work, it seems that because it's a loop that takes more than 200ms to complete it won't work, as you already expected. I've also tried some other things, and I thought maybe you could look into it. What i was thinking and trying to code but didn't work is the following: I tried to take the "timenow" and save that value when the longcondition gets triggered. Than take that value and add 1000 to it (1s) and than wait till timenow is equal to that specific value but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: This also doesn't work.
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
 
var int t = na

if longCondition
    t := timenow
    for i = 0 to 20000
        if timenow - t >= 1000
            strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

if shortCondition
    t := timenow
    for i = 0 to 20000
        if timenow - t >= 1000
            strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)

Comment: No, that won't work, because timenow is the current time. Also, pine processes bar per bar and it's likely that the execution time of your entire script over all of the available bars is much less than 1 second. So while you're waiting for 1 second to pass, your script already finished running.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy("xx")
emaLong = ema(close, 50)
emaShort = ema(close, 20)

longCondition = crossover()
shortCondition = crossover()

var wait_time := 0
if wait_time>0
     wait_time = wait_time - 1

if longCondition
     wait_time = 0
     strategy.entry()

if shortCondition
     wait_time = 24
     strategy.entry()
```

I am thinking somethign like this. Of course, this doesn't work. But it could be something that someone may further edit.

Comment: And I am seeking the same resolution too. Hopefully someone may come up with something

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
//@Version=5

// Define the number of bars to wait:

barsToWait = 10

// Declare a variable to keep track of the last traded bar:

lastTradeBar = 0

// Get the current bar index:

currentBar = bar_index

// Check if the number of bars passed is greater than the number of bars to wait:

if currentBar > lastTradeBar + barsToWait
    // If it is, then open a trade
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry", strategy.long)
    lastTradeBar := currentBar
```

You can also create the barstoWait as an input, then you can quickly change it on the fly while testing strategies. I am using it like this and it works.

Like this:

```
barsToWait = input.int(2,"Bars to Wait for Trades",1,20,1)
```